# Import a git repo into an empty branch

Tags: git

Lets say a project has been developed in one repo, and the project website was developed in another.

Is there a way to import the website repo, with full history, into an [empty branch](http://book.git-scm.com/5_creating_new_empty_branches.html) of the project repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git remote add rweb git://whereever
git fetch rweb
```

And voilà, you have it in one repository. Perhaps you then also want to create a branch out of it, to make it accessible and pushable:

```
git branch website rweb/master
git push origin website
```

Starting with an empty branches and dumping the website tree instead would have the drawback of losing all the history.

Comment: Nice. That does *exactly* what I wanted, and it was a lot simpler than I thought it was going to be. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be a case for git submodules

Comment: Submodules would require that the website be maintained in a seperate repo. Plus, I don't want the site in the project tree.

Comment: Ok, in that case use git remotes with fetch/push